# Ambigious name - worksheet change - double

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I'm attempting to add a second code to a single worksheet and keep getting the "Ambiguous name detected" error. Realise that I need to combine the two codes but having trouble doing so. here are the two codes, one below the other (I had to make the second sub because the cells can have manual input):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    Dim oldvalue, newvalue, sep As String
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng1 = Range("B199:B218,B223:B243,B247:B261,B266:B275,F120")
    Set rng2 = Range("C199:C218,C223:C243,C247:C261,C266:C275")

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng1) Is Nothing Then
        sep = " - "
    ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng2) Is Nothing Then
        sep = vbNewLine
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldvalue = Target.Value
    If oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = newvalue
    Else
        If InStr(1, oldvalue, newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = oldvalue & sep & newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = oldvalue
        End If
    End If
End sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo done

If Application.Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("F117")) Is Nothing Then GoTo done
application.enableevents=False
If Target.Value = 0 Then
'T1
Range("$A$145").Value = "X"
Range("$B$145").Value = "TestD4"
Range("$C$145").Value = "00000"
Range("$D$145").Value = "00000"
Range("$E$145").Value = "TestD4"
Range("$F$145").Value = "Test D4"
'T2
'Game 0
Range("A159").Value = "X"
Range("B159").Value = "Test D4"
Range("C159").Value = "0.00"
Range("D159").Value = "0.00"
Range("E159").Value = "0.00"
Range("F159").Value = "0.00"
Range("G159").Value = "0.00"
'Game 1
Range("A172").Value = "X"
Range("B172").Value = "Test D4"
Range("C172").Value = "0.00"
Range("D172").Value = "0.00"
Range("E172").Value = "0.00"
Range("F172").Value = "0.00"
Range("G172").Value = "0.00"
'Game 2
Range("A185").Value = "X"
Range("B185").Value = "Test D4"
Range("C185").Value = "0.00"
Range("D185").Value = "0.00"
Range("E185").Value = "0.00"
Range("F185").Value = "0.00"
Range("G185").Value = "0.00"

'T10
Range("A322").Value = "X"
Range("B322").Value = "X"
Range("C322").Value = "Test D4"
Range("D322").Value = "Test D4"
Range("E322").Value = "Test D4"

Else

'T1
Range("$A$145").Value = ""
Range("$B$145").Value = ""
Range("$C$145").Value = ""
Range("$D$145").Value = ""
Range("$E$145").Value = ""
Range("$F$145").Value = ""
'T2
'Game 0
Range("A159").Value = ""
Range("B159").Value = ""
Range("C159").Value = ""
Range("D159").Value = ""
Range("E159").Value = ""
Range("F159").Value = ""
Range("G159").Value = ""
'Game 1
Range("A172").Value = ""
Range("B172").Value = ""
Range("C172").Value = ""
Range("D172").Value = ""
Range("E172").Value = ""
Range("F172").Value = ""
Range("G172").Value = ""
'Game 2
Range("A185").Value = ""
Range("B185").Value = ""
Range("C185").Value = ""
Range("D185").Value = ""
Range("E185").Value = ""
Range("F185").Value = ""
Range("G185").Value = ""

'T10
Range("A322").Value = ""
Range("B322").Value = ""
Range("C322").Value = ""
Range("D322").Value = ""
Range("E322").Value = ""

End If

done:
    Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to take multiple actions on a change, then you can structure your code like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ProcessOne Target
    ProcessTwo Target
End Sub

Sub ProcessOne(Target As Range)
    'do something with Target
End Sub

Sub ProcessTwo (Target As Range)
    'do something else with Target
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks FunThomas and Tim Williams - worked like a charm!